# How can I get google trend result by city or state?

Tags: api, state, city, trend

I am using 
    http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly //for us
    http://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly //for india

These are providing result by country this working fine but I want to get result by city or state can any one help me to get result by city or state

I need trend result for metro detroit area.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I could find for your problem is in using the 'Explore' functionality in google trends to browse related terms (top and rising) via state. Unfortunatly there is not an atom feed for you to integrate to however the embed option has some html that points to a javascript file. Depending on your intended use you may be able to get what you want by exploring this avenue.

Explore trends for [Alabama](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#geo=US-AL&date=today%207-d&cmpt=geo).